# How to fix a result to 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it so my area and perimeter calculators result is fixed to 2 decimal places. How to do so?

```
<script>

var $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    //calculate

    function calculator() {
        var recLength = $("recLength").value ;
        var recWidth =  $("recWidth").value ;
        $("recArea").value = recLength * recWidth ;
        $("recPerim").value = 2 * recWidth + 2 * recLength ; 



    }

    window.onload = function() 
    {
        $("calculate").onclick = calculator;
    }   

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <main>
    <h1>Rectangle Area and Perimeter Calculator</h1>
        <div id="data">
            <label>Enter Length:</label>
            <input type="text" id="recLength"><br>

            <label>Enter Width:</label>
            <input type="text" id="recWidth"><br><br><br>

            <label>Rectangle Area:</label>
            <input type="text" id="recArea"><br>

            <label>Rectangle Perimeter:</label>
            <input type="text" id="recPerim"><br>
        </div>
```

Comment: `$("recArea").value = (recLength * recWidth).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @SantiagoHernández you should possibly make that an answer

Comment: I want to know who read this question and thought, "Yeah, this shows research effort".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
$("recArea").value = (recLength * recWidth).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was the toFixed  command I was just unsure of where to put it.